# Reading string from a URL and then loading it's image in an UIImageView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, nsurl

I've got the following code that loads on an UIImageView the image that I want from the internet:

```
NSString* mapURL = @"http://mydomain.com/image-320x480.png";
NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];

 UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
 [marcaBackground setImage:image];
 [imageData release];
 [image release];
```

I'd like instead of hardcoding the URL of the image, to load a string of another URL and then load that image on the UIImageView.

My URL returns just another URL in text format.

For example: `http://mydomain.com/url` returns  `http://mydomain.com/image-320x480.png`

How could I accomplish this task?

Comment: This sounds pretty messy. Why not make `http://mydomain.com/url` return a proper HTTP redirect rather than your own custom scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
NSData *imageData = 
   [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfUrl:
       [NSString 
           stringWithContentsOfUrl: 
             [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain.com"]
           encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding
           error: nil
       ]
   ];
```

Then proceed as you were already doing.

```
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
[marcaBackground setImage:image];
[imageData release];
[image release];
```

Comment: Excellent reply. Just needs correction of typo at initWithContentsOfUrl for initWithContentsOfURL. Thanks!